# Next.js read Firestore data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I found this Next.js starter to read data in Firestore v9, but it shows data after onclick.  In Next.js how would I write this to actually be consumable data without the click?

```
import { db } from '@/lib/firebase/initFirebase'
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore"
import { useUser } from '@/lib/firebase/useUser'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

const ReadDataFromCloudFirestore = () => {
    const { user } = useUser()
    const readData = async () => {
        try {
            const userDoc = doc(db, "myCollection", user.id)
            await getDoc(userDoc).then((doc) => {
                if (doc.exists()) {
                    console.log(doc.data())
                }
            })
            alert('Data was successfully fetched from cloud firestore! Close this alert and check console for output.')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            alert(error)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ margin: '5px 0' }}>
            <Button onClick={readData} style={{ width: '100%' }}>Read Data From Cloud Firestore</Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ReadDataFromCloudFirestore
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by simply removing the function and running the try/catch when the page opens.

```
const ReadDataFromCloudFirestore = () => {


        const { user } = useUser()
            try {
                const userDoc = doc(db, "myCollection", user.id)
                await getDoc(userDoc).then((doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists()) {
                        console.log(doc.data())
                    }
                })
                alert('Data was successfully fetched from cloud firestore! Close this alert and check console for output.')
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
                alert(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this earlier, but ran into this error:
Error: error: await isn't allowed in non-async function

Comment: What happens when you remove the word await

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but you can try adding `async` to the beginning of your arrow function, that should work.

This is what i mean:

```
const ReadDataFromCloudFirestore = async () => {


        const { user } = useUser()
            try {
                const userDoc = doc(db, "myCollection", user.id)
                await getDoc(userDoc).then((doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists()) {
                        console.log(doc.data())
                    }
                })
                alert('Data was successfully fetched from cloud firestore! Close this alert and check console for output.')
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
                alert(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is just an extension of the answer above, i don't have enough reputation to make a comment, i would have appended it to the answer